# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found + @JaversSpringDataAuditable

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, javers

I'm getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found`, when I use Javers Audit feature in my JPA repository class.

```
@JaversSpringDataAuditable
```

My service method(create/Update) is defined with `@Async` and it's handled using `Future`.

```
Future<T> updateEmployee(Employee employee) {
    //some code here
    return new AsyncResult<T>(employeeDTO);
}
```

Am I missing anything here?

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No 
>       thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: 
>       Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or 
>       processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are 
>       actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your 
>       code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In 
>       this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the 
>       current request.at
>
> org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131) ~[spring-web-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.currentRequestAttributes(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:275) ~[spring-web-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.access$400(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:64) ~[spring-web-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils$RequestObjectFactory.getObject(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:291) ~[spring-web-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils$RequestObjectFactory.getObject(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:286) ~[spring-web-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AutowireUtils$ObjectFactoryDelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(AutowireUtils.java:307) ~[spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
>               at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy146.getHeader(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>               at com.vz.uiam.common.audit.javers.ServletRequestAuthorProvider.provide(ServletRequestAuthorProvider.java:15) ~[uiam_common_cloud-1.0.11.jar:1.0.11]
>               at org.javers.spring.auditable.aspect.OnSaveAuditChangeHandler.handle(OnSaveAuditChangeHandler.java:17) ~[javers-spring-1.6.4.jar:na]
>               at org.javers.spring.auditable.aspect.JaversAuditableRepositoryAspect.applyVersionChange(JaversAuditableRepositoryAspect.java:94) ~[javers-spring-1.6.4.jar:na]
>               at org.javers.spring.auditable.aspect.JaversAuditableRepositoryAspect.applyVersionChanges(JaversAuditableRepositoryAspect.java:89) ~[javers-spring-1.6.4.jar:na]
>               at org.javers.spring.auditable.aspect.JaversAuditableRepositoryAspect.onVersionEvent(JaversAuditableRepositoryAspect.java:71) ~[javers-spring-1.6.4.jar:na]
>               at org.javers.spring.auditable.aspect.JaversAuditableRepositoryAspect.onSaveExecuted(JaversAuditableRepositoryAspect.java:59) ~[javers-spring-1.6.4.jar:na]
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
>               at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
>               at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621) [spring-aop-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:603) [spring-aop-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterReturningAdvice.afterReturning(AspectJAfterReturningAdvice.java:61) ~[spring-aop-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:53) ~[spring-aop-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168) [spring-aop-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85) [spring-aop-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
>               at com.vz.uiam.common.audit.aspect.JPAIdFieldNullifyAspect.monitor(JPAIdFieldNullifyAspect.java:55) ~[uiam_common_cloud-1.0.11.jar:1.0.11]
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
>               at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
>               at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621) [spring-aop-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610) [spring-aop-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68) [spring-aop-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168) [spring-aop-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) [spring-aop-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
>               at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy149.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

Answer (score 0):

Javers is trying to find the author of the modification in the current web request. However, since you seems not to be in the context of a web request this fail.

If you are truly not in a web request, it seems you need to provide another AuthorProvider bean than ServletRequestAuthorProvider (which may be the default).

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by Nyamiou The Galeanthrope is right, but just to clarify:

com.vz.uiam.common.audit.javers.ServletRequestAuthorProvider is definetly not a JaVers class but some implementation of the AuthorProvider interface.

By default (if you are using spring-boot-starter-data-jpa), JaVers gives you [SpringSecurityAuthorProvider](https://github.com/javers/javers/blob/master/javers-spring/src/main/java/org/javers/spring/auditable/SpringSecurityAuthorProvider.java).